# How do I add an element separated from a string to another array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to add the elements of the fourth column in each line of the file to an array, but now I don't know how to add the separated elements to another array. My approach seems to have some problems:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr
cat 2.csv | while read line
do
    IFS=',' read -ra str <<< "$line"
    # echo ${str[3]}
    arr+=(${str[3]})
done

for(( i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++)) do
    echo ${arr[i]};
done;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each process in a pipeline operates inside a subshell.  Thus, this code modifies `arr` inside a subshell.  No change to the environment survives outside the subshell.

```
cat 2.csv | while read line
do
    IFS=',' read -ra str <<< "$line"
    # echo ${str[3]}
    arr+=(${str[3]})
done
```

To avoid that, use redirection:

```
while read line
do
    IFS=',' read -ra str <<< "$line"
    # echo ${str[3]}
    arr+=(${str[3]})
done <2.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644557/2072269), there's no need to read the line, and the  read it again to split it. You can do the splitting the first time:

```
while IFS=, read -ra str
do
  arr+=("${str[3]}")  # Quote here if you don't want further splitting
done < 2.csc
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading into an a array, you could read into variables and throw away those you don't need:

```
while IFS=, read -r _ _ _ str _; do arr+=("$str"); done < 2.csv
```

This is only practical if the index you want is relatively low, though.

Another option, using `cut` and process substitution:

```
readarray -t arr < <(cut -d, -f4 2.csv)
```